# Migrar Informe Excel a Power BI

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerbi, hive

Tengo un reporte en excel que está estructurado de esta manera ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta información está almacenada en Base de datos access, la cual pertenecen a diferentes consultas:

```
Select producto, total, precio bruto, precio neto from productos where fecha='31/12/2022' and empresa='AlB';
```

Estas consultas se muestran en el reporte.

Quisiera llevar todo esto a Power BI, pero no comprendo como utilizarlo en lenguaje DAX o si lo más recomdable es hacerlo en SQL y luego mostrarlo en Power BI con la data ya lista de SQL Hive. Cuál es mejor en rendimiento?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: SI los datos están en un Access conecta PowerBi con ese Access. Luego mediante PowerQuery das formato a tus tablas para incorporarlas al modelo de datos.